# Ubuntu One sync folder to other destination

Tags: ubuntu-one

I've selected my documents folder in Ubuntu to sync with Ubuntu One.

On my Windows partition, I'd like to sync this contents with another folder like C:\ubuntushare. When I select the checkbox to sync my Documents folder, it automaticaly selects my documents folder in my user folder. Is it possible to change this location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to change the place where the folders are synced to. We do have it on our roadmap, but it's not implemented.

Comment: It's is unfortunate.... I have an Ubuntu One folder called Library, which conflicts with the Library folder of my Mac..any workaround?